# Issues with creating an image that runs

Tags: boot-issues, image, raspberry-pi-imager

I have a raspberry pi 4 and raspberry pi zero 2w at home. I have a single SD card with an image created a few years ago that runs the raspberry pi 4. For the raspberry pi zero 2w, I downloaded the image creator from the raspberry pi website. Then, I created an image with the 64 bit bullseye os option. Afterwards, the raspberry pi zero 2w is not being read by my laptop, and when I connect a monitor to it it goes to sleep. I put the same card in the raspberry pi 4, and it also does not run on this card. Then, I got multiple cards, and created images of every single os option from the imager, and neither the raspberry pi zero 2w nor will the raspberry pi 4 run on the cards. The only card they run on is the one created years ago for the raspberry pi 4.
The raspberry pi's will get to the "Welcome to raspberry pi" screen on a monitor, and then the monitor will go to sleep and never come on if I put a new card in them. For the raspberry pi zero 2w, the green light will flash, and then eventually become solid flashing every few minutes if booted on a new card.
Is there some trick to creating the image? I am not sure why no raspberry pi I have is running on images created from the raspberry pi website when every tutorial says to do this. I'd like some insight into what this problem is and how to fix it. Every computer store near me refuses to see a raspberry pi, and an engineer I showed it to could not figure it out either.

Comment: sounds like something is wrong with your laptop

Comment: I am not even go to try reading that wall of text.   Please  add some paragraph  breaks.

Comment: You should make sure `hdmi_safe=1` is uncommented in `/boot/config.txt` (ie., `config.txt` on the first partition, that is accessible from any computer), and any other HDMI settings are commented out, then try and boot with a monitor connected.